# Visual Studio 2013 Inherited include Directories & DirectX

Tags: visual-studio-2013, directx, include-path

I have an issue with the old DirectX SDK path being added to my VC++ Directories (inherited values) before the WindowsSDK path. I can't figure out for the life of me where these paths are being added from. What I need to know is: are these paths automatically added (by VS) somehow? If so, where/how? Or are they always user-defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found where the old SDK path was being added from - C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props, thanks to the discussion [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762659/vs2012-c-include-and-library-directories-are-not-set-correctly-in-new-projects).

I removed the old SDK path from there, since we only target new WindowsSDK. I imagine I'd run into issues if I'd need the old path again for some other project, but for now this does the trick.